# Trigger name as a variable's value

Tags: google-tag-manager

Is it possible to get the trigger name as a variable's value in Google Analytics? I would like to handle many `matches CSS selector` triggers in one tag, but I can't just use `Click Classes` variable to distinguish them (some tracked elements don't have their own classes or ids - they are defined in triggers as eg. children of `#example` element). Is there any other way to track elements like this or do I have to add classes/ids to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this could be solved by using a custom javascript variable to check whether a class or id is there or instead check the parent for a value recursively.

For example, a custom javascript value set up like below should check the element for a class or id and if not present search for one in the parent nodes:

```
function() {
  function getParentByClass($el) { 
  if ($el.id != "") {
    return $el.id;
  } else if ($el.className != "") {
    return $el.className;
  } else {
    return getParentByClass($el.parent());
  }
  }

  return function(e) {
      return getParentByClass(e.target);
  }

}
```

If you need to identify the unclassified children nodes you may be able to get the text content or other identifiable attributes for the event object. Hope this is what you were looking for. There is more info on custom event handlers on Simo Ahava's blog, especially this article: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/custom-event-listeners-gtm/